# How can I perform n-dimensional statistics aggregation in one Query DSL in Elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch

I just learned Elastic, and I want to write some code that analyses the user requests API in different time dimensions.

- How many times does the user request in one day?
- How many times does the user request in one week?
- How many times does the user request in one month?
- How many times does the user request in one year?

The code has shown below:

```
POST my-index/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "user_id.keyword": ["USER_ID"]
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "uri.keyword": "/api-path*"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1y/y",
              "lte": "now/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I should send the code to elastic four times in different @timestamp parameter(now-1d/d, now-1w/w, now-1m/m, now-1y/y). That will cost a lot of networks and computing resources.

Have any method that puts them in one request?

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

It is possible, with the [multi-search api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) of `Elasticsearch`

It looks like that:

```json
GET my-index-000001/_msearch
{ }
{"query" : {"match" : { "message": "this is a test"}}}
{"index": "my-index-000002"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}}
```

The client library of Elasticsearch do implement this feature.

- [python](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.4.1/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.msearch)
- [java](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_msearch)
- [js](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_msearch)